# Top Dock in a DockPanel is taking all the space

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, dockpanel

My code looks something like this:

```
<DockPanel>
  <Expander DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="Expander1">
     <local:ListView1 DataContext="{Binding Source1}"/>
  </Expander>
  <Expander DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="Expander2">
     <local:ListView1 DataContext="{Binding Source2}"/>
  </Expander>
  <Expander DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="Expander3">
     <local:ListView1 DataContext="{Binding Source3}"/>
  </Expander>
</DockPanel>
```

`ListView1` is just a user control that contains a `ListView`

I have the behavior set: when one Expander is open, all the other 2 Expanders will close.

[image]

[image]

The problem is that when `Expander1` is open and its content is more than the window height, it will have a scroll bar to scroll down for its content while `Expander2` and `Expander3` are not displayed. I think `Expander1` uses all the space on the UI and `Expander2` & `Expander3` get pushed out side of the UI. When `Expander2` is open, `Expander3` is pushed out of the UI and not displayed. What can I do so that when I open an Expander, the one(s) below it won't get pushed out of the UI?

Comment: Have you tried to set the `MaxHeight` property of the Expander control?

Comment: @JayV Thanks for your reply! I have thought of setting MaxHeight but I wasn't so sure about what I am gonna set it to since the window size could be adjusted.

Comment: When I suggested the dockpanel, I was thinking of writing a multibinding and multiconverter.  I then realised there could possibly be more than one open. If you only want one of the options at a time then I'd consider a tabcontrol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you're only allowing one open at a time.

Given that then the size logic is simpler and you could use just a converter with a fixed number.

My PoC:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Expander DockPanel.Dock="Top" MaxHeight="{Binding ActualHeight, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}, 
        Converter={local:AddConverter ValueToAdd=-46}}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
    </Expander>
    <Expander DockPanel.Dock="Top" MaxHeight="{Binding ActualHeight, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}, 
        Converter={local:AddConverter ValueToAdd=-46}}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
    </Expander>
    <Expander DockPanel.Dock="Top" MaxHeight="{Binding ActualHeight, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}, 
        Converter={local:AddConverter ValueToAdd=-46}}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
    </Expander>
</DockPanel>
```

And the converter

```
public class AddConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public double ValueToAdd { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double bound = (Double)value;
        return bound + ValueToAdd;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

[image]

As I mentioned in the comments.

You could make this more sophisticated with a multibinding and multiconverter. That could allow for height when 2 are open.

Comment: Thank you! Using a converter to make sure MaxHeight won't exceed ActualHeight is a good tip!